# Solving $Ax \approx b$ with $0 < x_i < 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a known matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n, m}$ and an input vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I'm looking for an algorithm to solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$
Ax \approx b
$$

but each $x_i$ must be between 0 and 1.

(n is 6, and m is in the range 1-100)

Minimizing square error would be fine.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Formulate it as a quadratic programming problem.

Choose $\epsilon > 0$ to be small.

$$\min \left\|Ax - b \right\|^2$$

subject to

$$\epsilon  \le x_i \le 1-\epsilon , \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.$$

Comment: it can be a linear optimization problem too if you use the 1-norm or the inf-norm instead of the 2-norm

Comment: ah, that's a good point.

Comment: Ok, and what algorithm would you use to solve such a problem?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming)'s a list of softwares

Comment: With $n=6$ sums of $m \le 100$ variables, the quadratic problem should still be within reach.